# How to install particular yarn version in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg

How to install yarn version 0.27.5 in ubuntu ? since the lattest update yarn version is 1.2.1.

Comment: This is a question better asked on SuperUser or AskUbuntu- not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pick any release of yarn by looking at https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases and scrolling and paging to version you need.

For yarn 0.27.5, go to https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/tag/v0.27.5 you can see all the packages for yarn 0.27.5.  Download yarn_0.27.5_all.deb (Ubuntu is a Debian-based Linux) then you can install it with `dpkg`.

```
# wget https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v0.27.5/yarn_0.27.5_all.deb
# dpkg -i yarn_0.27.5_all.deb
```